# Module javafx.base not found in java 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-13

I have configured javafx 11 with openjdk 13. I have added the `PATH_TO_FX` statically to the location of javafx.

[image: Image of PATH_TO_FX]

And in project structure I have configured openjdk 13 but still it is giving the error `Module javafx.base not found in java 11`

[image]

Comment: You need OpenJFX. I often use a project based on the **maven** build infrastructure, with library dependency management.

Comment: How will I get that

Comment: Every IDE can do maven or gradle projects. Search for `maven repo openjfx` and you'll find the (library) dependency to add. As one can expect many modules, jars, better use such a tool as maven. Search examples. I'll give a pom.xml (maven's project-object-module).

Comment: This is not directly related to your problem but why do you use such a weired combination of versions. It just doesn't make sense to use an old version of JavaFX with a younger but still not current version of Java. Why don't you just use Java15/JavaFX15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every IDE can do maven or gradle projects. Search for maven repo openjfx and you'll find the (library) dependency to add. As one can expect many modules, jars, better use such a tool as maven. Search examples.

A **pom.xml** might contain the following OpenJFX dependencies. I have copied them for java 13, which you are using too.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>junaid.muhammad</groupId>
    <artifactId>myjavafx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--illegal-access=permit</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Maybe the JavaFX plugin -->
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>.. MyApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'll hope you see the advantage: there are several modules that make up JavaFX.